# Inserting only unique rows into SQLite (python)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using `cursor.executemany` to insert batches of rows from CSV files into a SQLite table, some of which are expected to be duplicates based on the primary key field. When I execute the command, I predictably get an Integrity Error and nothing gets inserted.

How do I selectively insert only non-duplicate rows without having to manually filter them out ahead of time? I know in just pure Python you could simply create an error exception and skip the duplicate row--is there something similar I can implement in this use case?

Comment: You can [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) each batch, in case of IntegrityError you fall back to insert line by line instead of executemany for this batch; again, just EAFP each line and ignore IntegrityError.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I'm new to SQLite--but is this something I'd want to wrap in a BEGIN/END transaction to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply use `INSERT OR IGNORE` to ignore the duplicates.

http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: A `duplicate` is a row with it's primary key equal to another row or any column?

Comment: See the SQLite docs for the `ON CONFLICT` clause. It is any row that triggers the conflict, usually due to a `UNIQUE` constraint, but could also be a `CHECK` or other constraint. And the most common unique constraint is the primary key.

Answer (score 4):

One option is simply writing out the loop manually with an error catch instead of using `executemany`.

Pseudocode:

```
for row in csvfile:
   try:
       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO X (Y) VALUES (%s)' % row[rowdatapoint])
   except IntegrityError:
       pass
```

Probably not as efficient as `executemany`, but it will catch your error short of getting into more complicated SQL changes that would possibly involve you pregenerating a giant `INSERT` SQL string.

Answer (score 2):

Having duplicate records in Bulk Insert is a pain which results in failure of complete batch. However `ON CONFLICT` clause which is an extension to `INSERT` clause clears out impediments of duplicate records. There are multiple SQLite clauses available to handle such situations:

`INSERT OR IGNORE`  **Ignores** duplicate records

`INSERT OR REPLACE` **Replaces** the latest duplicate record with the least

More explanation:

1. https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html
2. https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html