# how to avoid duplicate insertion sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, react-native-sqlite-storage

Hi i added array of data as rows in local database which is got from backend, now i got new data with existing data from backend, i'm trying to add this data to local database but duplicates are creating

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
this.GENRES_TABLE_NAME +
" " +
"( " +
"_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
"genre_id integer, " +
"genre_name text, " +
" )";
```

i have this data in local database

```
    {
        "_id":1,
        "genre_id": 43,
        "genre_name": "*Born 1920 - 1925"
    },
    {
        "_id":2
        "genre_id": 44,
        "genre_name": "1920's and Before"
    },
    {
        "_id":3
        "genre_id": 45,
        "genre_name": "1930's"
    }
```

this is my new data

```
    {
        "genre_id": 43,
        "genre_name": "*Born 1920 - 1925"
    },
    {
        "genre_id": 44,
        "genre_name": "1920's and Before"
    },
    {
        "genre_id": 111,
        "genre_name": "new collection"
    }
```

i want to add `genre_id:111` record to local database, but my query adding all records to local database, this is my query

```
   let insertSQL = `INSERT INTO ${this.GENRES_TABLE_NAME} (genre_id 
    ,genre_name) VALUES `;
      genres.forEach((genre, index) => {
        insertSQL += `(${genre.id},"${genre.name}")`;
        if (index < genres.length - 1) {
          insertSQL += ",";
        }
      });
      insertSQL += ";";
      db.executeSql(insertSQL)
```

please help me

Comment: Since `genre_id` is already `UNIQUE` you should be able to use the SQLite-specific syntax `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO <table>`.

Comment: How are you getting duplicates? `genre_id` is unique in the database. Duplicates should not be allowed?

Comment: You're not using parameterized queries, which isn't safe. To protect your app from [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use parameterized queries everywhere.

Comment: @topsail After realizing I was getting duplicates I made the `genre_id` unique, after making that `genre_id` unique, my query is  preventing entire data from inserting if there were any duplicates in my array.

Comment: @amphetamachine Thanks, `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO <table>` is working for me

Comment: Yes, good answer - fairly straightforward but I didn't recall this option in sqlite. Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663164/inserting-only-unique-rows-into-sqlite-python/57326614#57326614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `genre_id` already has a `UNIQUE` constraint, you should be able to use the [SQLite-specific syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO <table>`, silencing what would otherwise be a unique constraint violation error.

Also, I noticed you're not using parameterized queries, which isn't safe. To protect your app from [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use parameterized queries everywhere.